# HttpClient request compress XML content with Accept, Content-encoding GZIP, and Decompress the response by GZIP in the environment of .Net core

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, gzip, httpclient, c#-3.0

I got the .Net Core service code like below. I will pass a string "xmlContent" with XML format into the HttpClient. But, the request needs to be Compressed by GZIP:

- Content-Encoding: gzip
- Accept-Encoding: gzip

Moreover, the response also need to be decompressed by GZIP as well.

Becuase we are using .Net core, so I have to use HttpClient to send the request and get response.

Does anyone who have experience in dealing with this issue?

```
    private string GetString(Uri url, string xmlContent)
    {
        using (var HttpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
            request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("GZIP"));                
            request.Content = new StringContent(xmlContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
            var response = HttpClient.SendAsync(request);

            var result = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;               

            return result;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this I am having the same issues